# Error in getting access token for Mailchimp. Returns {"error":"invalid_grant"}

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Got a code and I tried to get access token for it. I made a Curl request and executed it but only got error response as {"error":"invalid_grant"}. Here is my code:

```
    $url = 'https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token';
    $grant_type = 'authorization_code';
    $client_id = 'MY CLIENT ID';
    $client_secret = 'SECRET KEY';
    $redirect_url = urlencode('REDIREDT_URL');
    $code = $_GET['code'];;

    $post_field = array(
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'client_id' => $client_id,
        'client_secret' => $client_secret,
        'redirect_uri' => $redirect_url,
        'code' => $code,
        );

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    $value = http_build_query($post_field);
    //echo $value; exit;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $value);

    //echo $post_field;
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close( $ch );
    print_r($result); exit;
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724581/mailchimp-oauth2-in-asp-net-keep-returning-invalid-grant

Answer (score 1):

[From the documentation:][1]

> invalid_grant
> The provided authorization grant (e.g., authorization
> code, resource owner credentials) or refresh token is
> invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection
> URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to
> another client.

I would obtain a new authorization token.
[1]: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.2

Comment: A link to the manual in a comment would achieve the same as this

Comment: Thank You for your reply :) but i have doubled checked my credentials and found them right. One thing that scratches my mind is 'out-of-band' request. Do you have any idea how to make out of band request.

Comment: Out-of-band means you just need to make that request asynchronously on the server, not on the client (e.g. browser), because it exposes the client secret.

Comment: In the end, my issue with `invalid_grant` was caused by using `encodeURIComponent` on the redirect URI, and then passing this encoded value to the `request` config the second time. This caused double encoding, which caused the redirect URI's to mismatch and resulted in this error.